# In SQL,Why is the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' for DATE data type in an Insert statement giving error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When I tried this,

```
Insert into table abc values('name',2000,'1994-04-01');
```

I am getting an error showing that

> "Literal does not match format string".

The third parameter is the date datatype in the insert statement. I tried googling it,but it's the same syntax everywhere.Please help!!

Comment: See this http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: You haven't specified the column names. What order are the columns in the table?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: The order of the columns is name, salary(int), date.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Use an ansi date literal: `date '1994-04-01'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
--INSERT INTO table_abc
SELECT 'name', 2000, to_date('1994-04-01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
FROM DUAL D
```

Comment: Does it work? I tried using this thing in Oracle 11g . But it shows an error stating that "Expected from instead of Select".